# React Typescript not giving type checking errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm encountering a strange issue with React where TypeScript does not show any errors after running `npm start` or `npm build`. An example of my code is below, where I assign invalid values to the function arguments and variables. I get no errors with this code and it compiles fine, even though it should fail. I recently upgraded react-scripts from v3 to v4, which is the only thing I can think of that may have caused this. I'm using a mix of JS and TS.

```
export default function myFunction(
  value: Function = 100,
) {
    const test: string = 123
}
```

I do get warnings, but no errors:

```
Line 31:9:  'test' is assigned a value but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

Package versions from package.json

```json
"react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
"typescript": "^4.2.3",
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 2):

So somehow TypeScript started working again in the middle of my development. Oddly, it was still not working after the first few compiles, then all of the sudden started working. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

The most recent things I had done were

- Delete node_modules and reinstall
- Delete my tsconfig then let CRA/TypeScript generate a new one

My TypeScript version got downgraded too. I'm not sure if I did that or if npm did.

```
"react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
"typescript": "^4.1.3",
```

Here's my new tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```